# Negative continued fraction of Euler Mascheroni constant

Tags: continued-fractions, euler-mascheroni-constant

$\gamma$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant, has the following simple regular continued fraction:

$$\gamma=[0; 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,\dots]=0+
\cfrac{1}{
  1+\cfrac{1}{
    1+\cfrac{1}{
      2+\cfrac{1}{
        1+\ddots
      }
    }
  }
}$$

I wondered which would be its negative continued fraction, but after searching I have not found anything about it in the literature I have checked.

Just using rough approximation methods, I have derived that it seems that

$$\gamma=1-
\cfrac{1}{
  3-\cfrac{1}{
    2-\cfrac{1}{
      3-\cfrac{1}{
        2-\ddots
      }
    }
  }
}$$

(although there is an initial pattern in the alternating $2$ and $3$, this pattern ceases).

I would like to know if there is some way to transform a regular continued fraction into a negative continued fraction, to see if that transformation could give some valuable info about $\gamma$. Also, if the negative continued fraction of $\gamma$ is already known, it would be great if you could provide where I can consult it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this interesting research that I share with you in case you are interested in the relationship between the negative and positive continued fractions:

https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?filename=2&article=1183&context=hmc_theses&type=additional

According to Definition 8, the first terms of the negative continued fraction of the Euler Mascheroni constant would be:

$$\gamma=[1,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,5,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,...]$$